# how to make bot use reaction emoji for change embed using python

Tags: python, discord

I'm trying to make a bot that uses emoji to change the embed message like owo or some kind of music bot pls show me how
I'm just a guy who is interested in coding and just begin making a bot

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

You could catch the [`on_reaction_add`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_reaction_add) event.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    if (message.author.id == bot.user.id) and (str(reaction.message.id) == "id-of-message-to-be-edited"):
        reaction.message.edit(embed=Embed(title="new embed content"))
```

Or if you're using this in the flow of a command or a pre-called event, use [`discord.Client.wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for).

```py
@bot.command()
async def foo(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Say hello by reaction with !')
        def check(reaction, user):
            return user == message.author and str(reaction.emoji) == ''

        try:
            reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=60.0, check=check)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await channel.send('Bye ')
        else:
            await channel.send('Hello ')
```